# Math on Django queryset field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django model:

```
class Accounts(models.Model):
    account_code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

When a query the database I want the returned queryset to have its field `value`  divided by 1000.
How can I do this kind of math on a model field as I query the database?

Comment: In the same attribute? Because first of all, then this is *not* an `Integer` anymore, and furthermore it would make everything way more confusing. If you need to store values, you can use a `DecimalField`, which stores the numbers according to the defined precision.

Comment: Edited to change to DecimalField. Thanks. When I do `Accounts.objects.all()` all `values` entries in the Queryset would be divided by 1000.

Comment: How are you going to use this divided value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a property on your model using the `property` decorator. This property would not be defined in the database, but would be accessible on each object once queried.

For example:

```
class Accounts(models.Model):
    account_code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def divided_value(self):
        return self.value / 1000
```

Then you can access the `divided_value` on each account instance as a normal property, e.g. `account.divided_value`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this is actually possible to do in a queryset, even using annotation (I'm actually pretty certain that it's not possible). My first answer is space inefficient, as you'd have to store the same value in two forms, and my second answer is what I would do, and uses the front end to handle the division:

**Answer One: A second value field**

In your model, you can define a field `formatted_value` that is also a decimal, but with 6 decimal places (to account for the division by 1000). In the `save` function, or in a `pre_save` signal, you can divide `value` by 1000 and save that in the `formatted_value` field.

This answer is sub-optimal because you will waste space in your database.  I believe that a better answer is this:

**Answer Two: View or Front End Handling**

In my projects, I often need to manipulate numbers held in the database to output some sort of analytics tool.  I return the raw numbers to the front end (as long as they are not sensitive), and then handle the math in the front end using Javascript.  This passes the burden of computation to the client, and simplifies your Django.  The pro of this is that you can then make the front end interactive and allow the user to change values that affect the analytics they are looking at.

I have a feeling that you are looking for something simpler.  If you have a view that always needs to return the `value/1000`, you can handle this in your view by getting your list of `Accounts` using `Accounts.objects.all()` and then looping through each and dividing `value` by 1000.

Comment: I´ll try the approach from your last paragraph. Think it´ll work.